# Asp.net dropdown control appears twice

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a .NET Framework 4.5.2 Web Application.

I encountered an issue during the course of development. The issue was that, when I used a hierarchical folder structure, and placed my Default.aspx page in a top directory, I could not access other pages in the lower hierarchy...I was getting the error, "*The resource could not be found*"

I noticed that the browser was appending the name of the current directory(*Portal*) to the relative path, like this:

[localhost:50229/Portal/~/Portal/Users/Learner/EditProfile.aspx]

To fix this error, I added a *runat="server"* to my anchor tag like so:

```html
<a runat="server" href="~/Portal/Users/Learner/EditProfile.aspx">
```

and it worked, just fine.

The next issue I encountered was that, the *j Query* scripts in the Master page where active in the inheriting pages, as long as they were in the same directory as the Master page. But as soon as the page was moved to a different directory the scripts became inaccessible.
To fix this I used the ScripManager, in the following way (In Master Page);

```
<!--
    There was an issue where when a page inheriting from this master page, was called from a different
    folder, the scripts where not working. Using the script manager resolved this problem. 
-->
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Portal/portal_assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Portal/portal_assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Portal/portal_assets/plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Portal/portal_assets/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Portal/portal_assets/plugins/node-waves/waves.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Portal/portal_assets/js/admin.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Portal/portal_assets/js/demo.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

After having resolved these two issues a new bug has surfaced. I.e. On every page that inherits from this Master page, if there is a *dropdownlist control*
on that page, the *dropdownlist control* appears twice, whilst other controls like a textbox, appear just once.

Here is a snapshot:
[Duplicated dropdownlist control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCJA3.png)

When I click on the dropdownlist on top, it is blank

When I click on the dropdownlist at the bottom it shows the list content, and when I select an Item on the bottom list, it shows up as selected on both the dropdown lists like so:

[Dupliacted dropdown list, showing selected content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bdaZ.png)

I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to resolve this issue.

P.S. I mentioned the 2 errors above and their solutions, because I think the current issue, maybe related to the way I implemented the fixes to those errors.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve this bug, with the help of a more experienced student.

The Issue arose because I Was Referencing Two Bootstrap Script Files In

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
```

1st.

```html
<asp:ScriptReference Path="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" />
```

2nd.

```html
<asp:ScriptReference Path="assets/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js"
```

When I removed the 2nd Reference.... to bootstrap-select.js the issue resolved.
I may be wrong, but I think bootstrap-selec.js contains a subset of the scripts int bootstrap.js

So It could be that I was calling the same function twice, causing it to duplicate the dropdown lists.